# What is that {CODE} used in Win registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\{CODE}?

Tags: window, windows-installer, registry, guid

After a msi is installed, the Windows Registry will add a key **{CODE}** inside **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer**. I would expect that **{CODE}** to be the Product Code of the application being installed, but they don't match.

For example, if I install a msi package whose Product Code is {E4703DAD-63CA-4A57-B9E3-D7887318B036} I see that the key added is **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\FAD3074EAC3675A49B3E7D4837810B63**

I did see that such **{CODE}** is constant regardless different version or package code of my application (which is why I was expecting it to be - or have some relation - to the product code).

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured how that **{CODE}** is constructed. I see some references of it being called as a compressed GUID and it is indeed based on Product Code. That **{CODE}** is the Product Code "reversed".

You can easily see if you align both **{CODE}** and product code with the dashes

```
Product Code:    {E4703DAF-63CA-4A57-B9E3-D7887318B036}

{CODE} with dash: FAD3074E-AC36-75A4-9B3E-7D4837810B63
```

The first 3 groups are basically a direct reverse (63CA -> AC36), while the last 2 groups are reversed inside a set of 2 chars basis (B9E3 -> 9B3E).

Comment: Yes, this is correct. What is the use case scenario? What do you need to do? [Just get the values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63713342/129130) or some specific admin task of what nature?

Comment: This question here came as part of debugging this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63709725/why-packagecode-is-not-being-updated-in-registry-after-a-small-update