# Why packagecode is not being updated in registry after a small update or minor upgrade?

Tags: windows-installer, uninstallation

I have an application installed and I am doing a small update (new msi with new package code but same version, product code and upgrade code). The update works fine but I noticed that I am not able to uninstall the software later (it gives an error saying that cannot find the source file and ask me to locate it. If I point the original MSI file - not the new one - that the uninstall occurs fine).

I think that is due to the package code of the new msi not replacing the former package code value in the registry (HCR\Installer\Products\GUID).

How can I force the installation of the new msi update that registry? I already tried using REINSTALL=ALL with REINSTALLMODE=vomus (vamus, and several other combinations).

I see the same issue when doing a minor upgrade (new package code, new version but same product code and same upgrade code).

My msi file as created using Installshield.

Comment: Small updates are not recommended. Is there a particular reason why you want to use it instead of a minor upgrade? Did you change [the package code](https://docs.revenera.com/installshield26helplib/helplibrary/MajorMinorSmall.htm)? (look towards bottom).

Comment: By the way, it is `REINSTALLMODE` and not `REINSTALL_MODE`. You can try `REINSTALLMODE=voums`. And the reason I ask about package code is that it certainly will not work without changing it.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul thanks for the interest in helping figuring out the issue. I used REINSTALLMODE (REINSTALL_MODE was a typo when writing the question, I just fixed it). About the packagecode, yes they are different and I can confirm it since when I install the new version directly (so, no upgrade) I see the correct package code there in registry. It is just when installing the new version on top of the old one that it appears that the packagecode doesn't get updated in the registry and keeps referring the old msi package code.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul, I tried both (small update and minor upgrade) and get same uninstall issue. The only way that worked so far was doing a major upgrade (different product code, same upgrade code). I updated the question to reflect that info.

Comment: Did you test on a virtual? Try that if you didn't. You could have a dirty-state on that test box you use.

Comment: good idea. I will try that and update here.

Answer (score 1):

After several tentatives, I gave up using small upgrades and I am using major upgrades (new project code, new package code, same upgrade code) with the setup.exe from installshield.

But just as an extra info, I think the issue I was facing with the small upgrade is somehow related with the setup.exe created by installshield. I was able to do small upgrade using .msi files and the uninstall worked fine (the 2nd msi file must be installed via cmd line "**msiexec.exe /i \product.msi REINSTALLMODE=vomus REINSTALL=ALL**"). If you just try to install update via double click on the msi Windows you will give you a message that the product is already installed).

As sugested by @Stein Åsmul, just go with the major upgrade.

Here are some links that I found related to that issue:

https://community.flexera.com/t5/InstallShield-Forum/Minor-Upgrade-breaks-Uninstall/td-p/115568

https://docs.revenera.com/installshield24helplib/installshield24helplib.htm#helplibrary/MinorUpgradeRuntime.htm?Highlight=REINSTALLMODE

https://community.flexera.com/t5/InstallShield-Forum/Reinstallmode-is-defaulting-to-vomus/td-p/24565

http://www.msigeek.com/1256/how-do-you-create-a-minor-upgrade-for-an-application-using-installshield
https://vincechan.me/2016/05/17/reinstallmode-vs-reinstallmodetext/